# Issue with Appending a JSON Array in a PostgreSQL Function

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, stored-procedures

I'm encountering an issue when attempting to append a JSON array or object into another JSON array within a PostgreSQL function. It seems that the array_append function is inserting the JSON as a string, resulting in an unexpected format in the output.

Currently, I'm getting output like this:

> {"{"category_id":8,"category_name":"08 Candy","is_active":true,"category_name_app":"Candy","display_order":7}"}
> However, I'd like the output to be in this format so that I can easily decode it in my code:

> [{"category_id":8,"category_name":"08 Candy","is_active":true,"category_name_app":"Candy","display_order":7}]

Below is the logic of my function:

```
    for all_categories in select * from categories where is_active = '1' loop
            show_at_homepage = 0;
        
            for current_subcat in select * from public."V_category_to_sub_category_w_names" where category_id = all_categories.category_id and sub_category_is_active = '1' loop
                
                
                select * into product_count from public."V_APP_products_w_sub_categories" where sub_category_id = current_subcat.sub_category_id and store_id = get_store_id and is_deleted='0';
                if count(product_count) > 0 then
                    
                    show_at_homepage = 1;
                                
                
                end if;
                
            end loop;
            
            if show_at_homepage = 1 then
                    select row_to_json(all_categories) into cat_json;
                    
                    select array_append(my_json_result_array,cat_json) into my_json_result_array;
                end if;
        
        
    end loop;
    return my_json_result_array;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `array_append` to any kind of array of postgres data types, including `json[]`, but you can't apply it to a json array which is of type `json`. In your case, you need to apply the json functions and operators, see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html), and more specifically the `json_build_array` function :

Replace

```
select array_append(my_json_result_array,cat_json) into my_json_result_array
```

By

```
select json_build_array(my_json_result_array,cat_json) into my_json_result_array
```

Or when you use `jsonb` instead of `json` which is the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) recommendation :

```
select jsonb_build_array(my_json_result_array,cat_json) into my_json_result_array
```

Comment: This is good but i want to append this jsonb array as an array into my_json_result_array. I can't do it. when i use array_append, it appends cat_json into my_json_result_array_array as string.  so even if it shows the brackets like array, it wraps it with  double quotes and becomes a string.

Comment: OK look at the updated answer and tell me if it fits your need.

Comment: this was close but when i jsonb_build_array it inserts outside the array. let me explain. what i want is like this [//here will be appended categories as array] but with json_build_array, it gives me like [[{category1}],category2]. i have to append it in the same array as category1

Comment: Based on your last comment, I come back to my initial answer : `SELECT '[]' :: jsonb || my_json_result_array :: jsonb || cat_json :: jsonb` will return `[my_json_result_array , cat_json] :: jsonb`. If this does not answer your question, please provide a full set of data sample : my_json_result_array, cat_json and the expected result after the concatenation.